# Android webview js communication with activity

Tags: javascript, android, webview

My app runs in a webview and it communicates with my activity which holds DB through a JS interface.

It queries DB through interface methods.

The only thing that can be passed between them are strings, but as this string get bigger it takes more time to pass it both direction.

Is there anyway to reduce this time? I thought of a way to compress data passing between them.

Or maybe problem is from somewhere else I don't know!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test I found out that transmission between Android and JS is slow because of the nature of implementation and there is nothing we can do about that, So I moved the db to the webview using WebSQL.